# Updating text box from another class

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm trying to update a text box from a class called 'hex' to the main form. Within the class 'hex' I have the following code:

```
        Main m = new Main();
        m.updateTextBox(convertedHex);
```

the code passed the variable to the main form to the method called 'updateTextBox' as shown below:

```
    public void updateLog(string input)
    {
        textBox2.AppendText(input);
    }
```

Sorry if this seems like a silly questions I have been stuck for a while, all the links on my google searches are now purple so I was hoping if someone could explain this to me. Many thanks.

Comment: What is your startup form? if it is Main, you are creating a new instance of Main and will not update your UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this kind of method inside your Main class where textBox is created and call it from outside.

Lets say you added the code in your `Program.cs` class to start new

```
    // Add this code in Program.cs (or similar where you start the gui
    public static readonly Main MainLogWindow = new Main();

    // Add this code in Main.cs class 
    private delegate void NameCallBack(string varText);
    public void UpdateTextBox(string input) {
        if (InvokeRequired) {
            textBox.BeginInvoke(new NameCallBack(UpdateTextBox), new object[] {input});
        } else {
            textBox.Text = input;
            // textBox.Text = textBox.Text + Environment.NewLine + input // This might work as append in next line but haven't tested so not sure
        }
    }
```

Call it like: `Program.MainLogWindow.UpdateTextBox("test test");` from anywhere assuming that you have `MainLogWindow` open

This will also allow you to call updates from within other threads.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I get this error 

"Error Cannot assign to 'AppendText' because it is a 'method group'"

Do you know what I'm doing wrong, I copied the code into

namespace WindowsPrefetchSearch
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {

        string root = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);


        public Main()
        {         
            InitializeComponent();
        }


//put the code here, many thanks!

Comment: Change AppendText to .Text and let me know if it works. I assumed AppendText is something that works for you.. I've edited source to make it sure. If it will work then you can try using it like `textBox.Text = textBox.Text + input` to simulate AppendText that you wanted to do.

Comment: .Text seems to work, but I can't call it from another class for some reason as it does not exist in the current context. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Updated it again. Hard to do it without testing :)\

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply but when I use your code I get the following error within program.cs

"SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application." 

It's an over due to the below.
"Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);"

Comment: My program.cs looks like:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsPrefetchSearch
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]

        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        public static readonly Form1 MainLogWindow = new Form1();
    }
}

Comment: Ignore those comments, I managed to fix the error but nothing is showing up within the textbox even though I know it's receiving the string as I can output it to the screen..

Comment: So did it worked or not in the end ? You accepted is an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You have not given us very much information to go on. But as I said in my comment if your startup form is `Main`, the code that you are showing is creating a new `Main` Form and any changes made to it will not appear in your UI. You need to pass the form instance to the Hex class constructor. I would do something like this(assuming that the namespaces are the same, they are on the same thread, and your Hex Class is not Static. if on different threads you need to use the Method shown by MadBoy)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Hex hex;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        hex = new Hex(this);
    }
}


class Hex
{
    Form1 m;

    public Hex( Form1 frm)
    {
        m = frm;
        m.updateTextBox("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I have used MadBoys method. Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your class, presumably a business object, generally shouldn't be concerned with updating the UI. It doesn't particularly need to know that you even *have* a UI. But there are a couple of different useful approaches you could use.

1) Simply have your UI invoke your business object's method, and let the method return a value, and then the UI can choose to display it.

```
// inside Main form
var hex = new Hex();
string convertedHex = hex.GetConvertedHex(someArgument);
UpdateTextBox(convertedHex);
```

2) Have your business object expose an event. The arguments for the event would include whatever string that needs to be broadcast to whomever subscribes to the event. The UI would then be one of the subscribers.

Of the two ideas, I would generally opt for the first unless you actually do need an event model.

Answer (score 0):

jest simple no need to do all of this make text box public from the properties and pass the current form object to the class throudh a method like this

```
public void mthod(){

//crete a obj of the class

cls1 obj=new clas1();

obj.smethod(this); 

}
```

now in the class  can cal it like this

```
smethod(from1 obj){
obj.textbox.text="";
}
```